# how to connect SQL Server 2005 express database to java

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-server-2005-express

I want to create a JDBC connection with SQL Server  Express 2005 when i tried the following code i got exception
my code is

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class PrintFileToPrinter{

public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://TOSHIBA-PC/SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=COSEC;user=sa;password=22484;";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
    if (conn != null) {
        System.out.println("Connected");
    }
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException exception){
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

and the error showing is

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host localhost, named instance SQLEXPRESS has failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names, check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434, and for SQL Server 2005 or later verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getInstancePort(SQLServerConnection.java:3163)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.primaryPermissionCheck(SQLServerConnection.java:953)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:816)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:716)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
at textfilemaker.JdbcSQLServerConnection.main(JdbcSQLServerConnection.java:32)
```

database details are follows
[image]

Comment: There are a few possibilities , jdbc:sqlserver://TOSHIBA-PC/SQLEXPRESS:1433 can become `jdbc:sqlserver://LOCALHOST\\SQLEXPRESS:1433` or you need to turn off TCP Dynamic Ports via the  `SQL Server Configuration Manager`

Comment: @KennethClark while i edited the code as u mentioned the below error is showing & TCP Dynamic Ports are already off. Error: The TCP/IP connection to the host LOCALHOST, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".

Comment: Have you tried `telnet` ? you can open a command prompt and type `telnet` ipaddress 1433 , if you get a connection then your firewall at least allows connections

Comment: @KennethClark  telnet is not working in my system enviornment